# error trying to set up basic chat app with node.js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to set up a basic chat app with node.js/express/socket.io but for some reason when the client sends message (this works, another client will get the message) it also refreshes the client and the url goes from localhost:3000 to localhost:3000/? (adds /? to end, i don't know what this means). I cant find anything wrong in my code after looking at it for hours. I have:

server.js:

```
let app = require('express')();
let http = require('http').Server(app);
let io = require('socket.io')(http);
let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => { res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html') });

http.listen(port,() => { console.log('listening on *:' + port) });

    io.on('connection', socket => {
        socket.on('chat', text => {
        io.sockets.emit('chat', `<p>${text}</p>`);
    });

});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<style>
    .chat_view{
        height: 300px;
        width: 200px;
        border: 5px ridge black;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="chat" id="chat">
    <div class="chat_view" id="chat_view">
    </div>
    <form id="chat_form">
        <input type="text" title="chat_input" id="chat_input" style="width: 206px">
    </form>
</div>
<script>
let socket = io();

$('#chat_form').submit( () => {
    let text = $('#chat_input').val();
    socket.emit('chat', text);
});

socket.on('chat', text => {
    let chat_view = document.getElementById('chat_view');
        chat_view.innerHTML += text;
        chat_view.scrollTop = chat_view.scrollHeight;
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and package.json:

```
{
  "name": "RatScrew",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
$('#chat_form').submit((event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    let text = $('#chat_input').val();
    socket.emit('chat', text);
});
```

The default method used when submiting the form is the GET method, which makes the server send `index.html` again and the page refreshes.
You may want to have a look at https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html

Answer (score 3):

If you're listening to the submit event, that means the form will actually try and POST to the server (which will in your case refresh the screen).  If you're using JavaScript to communicate with the server and don't need the form data to get posted by the browser directly, just return false from your callback. Some browsers also want you to call e.preventDefault() as well.

Comment: i really dont need to form i just want the input to submit when enter is pressed, is there something like .addEventListener('enter', () =>... that would make the input act on enter?

Comment: You could change the input to a button rather than a submit button, then handle it's click event.

Comment: yes i know how to do that, but i want the text to be send when enter is pressed.

Comment: That would be another question, but there is plenty of tutorials about it. Basically, you'll listen for a keyup event and then check to see which key it was and do your Ajax callif it's the enter key